# No row returns when SUM is selected with other columns

Tags: mysql

Hy,
I'd like to get some rows of a table and a SUM with rows of another table in the same SELECT.
Here is my code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, u.username, coalesce(SUM(v.value), 0) AS nbrVotes
FROM class_not_found.answers a, class_not_found.users u, class_not_found.votes v
WHERE a.question_id = :questionId
AND a.user_id = u.user_id
AND v.answer_id = a.answer_id
GROUP BY answer_id
```

So I'd like to SUM values of rows of 'vote' table when the row has the answeer's id... It's working when I have votes for an answer... but when there is no vote for the answer... I don't have any rows in the return, but I'd like to have '0'...
What can I do ?

When there is some rows with the answer's ID : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/64o8M.jpg

Where no rows with the answer's ID : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkW0a.jpg

Thank's for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to `v` so as to return rows when an answer has no votes. Rewriting your query with explicit `JOIN`s (the preferred way):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, u.username, coalesce(SUM(v.value), 0) AS nbrVotes
FROM class_not_found.answers a
JOIN class_not_found.users u ON u.user_id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN class_not_found.votes v ON v.answer_id = a.answer_id
WHERE a.question_id = :questionId
GROUP BY a.answer_id
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for ur answer! It's right... I used Join for a project before. But for this one, we haven't seen JOIN, so I didn't used it... thanks!